# antlr javascript, webpack and angularjs integration issue

Tags: angularjs, webpack, antlr, antlr4

I am facing some issue in using webpack generated bundle in my angularjs application.I am working on the integration of webpack with antlr javascript runtime(antlr4).I am following this document.
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md

I was able to generate a webpack bundle that includes all the antlr javascript runtime files and generated code (Lexer.js/Parser.js/Listener.js).

Now I am trying to use this bundle in my angularjs(1.x) application. I have included the webpack bundle in my html file like this.

```
 <script src="js/app/antlr/runtime/antlr4Runtime.js"></script>
```

After that I am trying to use antlr4 in my angularjs service like this.

**sample code snippet**

```
var chars = new antlr4.InputStream(someText);
```

and I am getting this error

**Error:**

ReferenceError: antlr4 is not defined.
can anyone please help me here.